# Redis mirror datacenter for active-active (xdcr feature)

Tags: redis, replication, mirror

Newbie to redis here so please bear with me.
I am looking for a method to have dual datacenter in active-active configuration. My need here is that:

1. if a datacenter goes down the other datacenter should not need any intervention to carry on working
2. Networking issues, if they occur, should not prevent one or the other datacenter to fail on set/get redis calls.
3. Restarting failed datacenter should have a means mirror the working redis' data back before going active

I have been reading up on replication abilities of redis, what I understand is there is

1. master-slave(s) replication
2. A cluster can have masters that are sharded
   But what I haven't seen is a cluster replicating to another cluster.

Question:

1. Is there a architecture design where all redis in one dc replicate with the other? (Looks like couchbase appears to have this)
2. I do see a keyspace notifier which can be used in a pub/sub, what i want to know is whether I can use it to pub/sub redis to redis from one dc to the other to act as replication.

Comment: Hi, recommend going through the following list of options. CRDT work satisfies all your requirements: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvKSeo75Rgk

Comment: Thanks for the info Cihan, will review it more closely, but at high level: multi-mastering is in v5.0 which is yet to come?

Comment: yes - few more weeks to go. tweet at @cihangirb if you'd like to try it earlier.